# How do I test this Custom UI Class to have code coverage

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, mockito, expresso

I made a custom UI class `EzCustomEditTextEmail` by extending `TextInputEditText` and have written the test class (`EmailUITest` ) for the same in android(test) package. I am trying to achieve code coverage for the Custom UI class and used Mockito for the same . write now what I am trying is to verify the line `setMaxLines(1)` in the `inIt()` method of `EzCustomEditTextEmail` class and getting **NullPointerException** at the `constructor` at `super(context)`

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;


public class EzCustomEditTextEmail extends TextInputEditText {
    public EzCustomEditTextEmail(Context context) {
        super(context);
        inIt();
    }

    public EzCustomEditTextEmail(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        inIt();
    }

    public EzCustomEditTextEmail(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttrs) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttrs);
        inIt();
    }

    private void inIt() {
        setMaxLines(1);
        setEditTextMaxLength(50);
        setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
        setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
    }

    public void setEditTextMaxLength(int length) {
        InputFilter[] filterArray = new InputFilter[1];
        filterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(length);
        setFilters(filterArray);
    }

    public boolean isValidEmail() {
        return (!TextUtils.isEmpty(getText()) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(getText().toString().trim()) && Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(getText().toString().trim()).matches());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter) {
        if (text.length() > 0) {
            if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(text).matches()) {
                requestFocus();
                setError("Invalid Email");
            }
        } else {
            setError(null);
        }
    }

}
```

**My test Class**

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class EmailUITest {
    @Mock
    EzCustomEditTextEmail ezCustomEditTextEmail;
    @Mock
    Context context;

    // Initializing Mockito and setup Pre-Test
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        ezCustomEditTextEmail = new EzCustomEditTextEmail(context);
    }

    // Test Method
    @Test
    public void callVerifyNumberAPI() throws InterruptedException {
        verify(ezCustomEditTextEmail, times(1)).setMaxLines(1);
    }

}
```

I'm getting **NullPointerException** at the `constructor` -> `super(context)`

Comment: Is this a `JUnit` test? Don't bother testing Android components (in this case, subclasses of `android.view.View`) with unit tests - JUnit runs on the local JVM and knows nothing of Android components. Write integration tests with Espresso instead. Also, don't mock the class that's under test. You will also find your logic simpler test if you use an MVP design pattern, move any logic out of your view and into a `Presenter`, and run unit tests on that rather than on the view itself.